# Filling upper area from area chart in python plotly

Tags: pandas, graph, plotly

I have an issue coloring a plotly area graph.

My data is the following:

```
 class1       class2      class3      class4
    0            0            0          0             
    0            0            1          1             
    1            0            0          3             
    0            0            0          2    
    0            0            0          2
    0            0            0          2
    0            0            0          2
    0            0            0          1
    0            0            0          1
    0            0            0          1
    0            0            0          1
    0            0            0          1
    0            0            0          2
```

And I'm painting it like this:

```
trace0 = dict(
        x = new_index,
        y = class1['num_users'],
        hoverinfo = 'x+y',
        mode = 'lines',
        line=dict(width=0.5,
                  color='rgb(58, 203, 215)'),
        stackgroup = 'one',
        name = '[1,{}] '.format(lower_q) ) 
trace1 = dict(
        x = new_index,
        y = class2['num_users'],
        hoverinfo = 'x+y',
        mode = 'lines',
        line=dict(width=0.5,
                  color='rgb(177, 193, 123)'),
        stackgroup = 'one',
        name = '[{},{}] '.format(lower_q + 1, medium_q) ) 
trace2 = dict(
        x = new_index,
        y = class3['num_users'],
        hoverinfo = 'x+y',
        mode = 'lines',
        line=dict(width=0.5,
                  color='rgb(243, 161, 203)'),
        stackgroup = 'one',
        name = '[{},{}] '.format(medium_q + 1, upper_q) ) 
trace3 = dict(
        x = new_index,
        y = class4['num_users'],
        hoverinfo = 'x+y',
        mode = 'lines',
        line=dict(width=0.5,
                  color='rgb(184, 178, 247)'),
        stackgroup = 'one',
        name = '>= {}'.format(upper_q + 1) ) 
trace4 = dict(
        x = new_index,
        y = class4['num_users'],
        hoverinfo = 'x+y',
        mode = 'lines',
        line=dict(width=0.5,
                  color='rgb(178, 241, 247)'),
        stackgroup = 'one',
        name = 'upper area' )

    data = [trace0, trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4]
```

I just want to paint a **filled area chart** for the 4 columns of the dataframe, but note I added an extra trace, `trace4` in order to paint the upper area. The result I get is the following:
[image]

But note that the expected output is that the blue upper area covers the whole upper part of the graph, like it does here:

[image]

Any help on how to fill in the upper area of the graph will be welcome.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: read the [docs](https://plot.ly/python/filled-area-plots/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're not getting the stacked area to fill 100% of the chart is because of the way a stacked area chart works and is rendered in plotly. The "total stack" at each x-axis value will be the sum of y-axis values from each series. If the sum of values of each of your traces does not equal the same value for all x values then the shaded-areas won't fill the whole plot.

In your example, if you want to paint the "extra area" then you would need to create a trace whose y value is `max(sum(trace0:trace3)) - sum(trace0:trace3)[x_value]`.

Code to complete this in your example looks like

```
max_value = max(df.sum(axis='columns')) # calculate max y-value in stack area chart
df['extra_fill'] = max_value - df.sum(axis='columns') # calculate "extra fill" value
```

Here is a complete code to accomplish this in a Jupyter notebook .
Copy this to your clipboard so `pd.from_clipboard` works.

```
 class1       class2      class3      class4
    0            0            0          0
    0            0            1          1
    1            0            0          3
    0            0            0          2
    0            0            0          2
    0            0            0          2
    0            0            0          2
    0            0            0          1
    0            0            0          1
    0            0            0          1
    0            0            0          1
    0            0            0          1
    0            0            0          2
```

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

# manipulate df to make it look like code in question
df = pd.read_clipboard()
max_value = max(df.sum(axis='columns')) # calculate max y-value in stack area chart
df['extra_fill'] = max_value - df.sum(axis='columns') # calculate "extra fill" value
class1 = df[['class1']].rename(columns={'class1': 'num_users'})
class2 = df[['class2']].rename(columns={'class2': 'num_users'})
class3 = df[['class3']].rename(columns={'class3': 'num_users'})
class4 = df[['class4']].rename(columns={'class4': 'num_users'})
extra_fill = df[['extra_fill']].rename(columns={'extra_fill': 'num_users'})

new_index = pd.date_range('2017-12-31', '2019-01-01', freq='M')

trace0 = dict(
        x = new_index,
        y = class1['num_users'],
        hoverinfo = 'x+y',
        mode = 'lines',
        line=dict(width=0.5,
                  color='rgb(58, 203, 215)'),
        stackgroup = 'one',
        ) 
trace1 = dict(
        x = new_index,
        y = class2['num_users'],
        hoverinfo = 'x+y',
        mode = 'lines',
        line=dict(width=0.5,
                  color='rgb(177, 193, 123)'),
        stackgroup = 'one',
        ) 
trace2 = dict(
        x = new_index,
        y = class3['num_users'],
        hoverinfo = 'x+y',
        mode = 'lines',
        line=dict(width=0.5,
                  color='rgb(243, 161, 203)'),
        stackgroup = 'one',
        ) 
trace3 = dict(
        x = new_index,
        y = class4['num_users'],
        hoverinfo = 'x+y',
        mode = 'lines',
        line=dict(width=0.5,
                  color='rgb(184, 178, 247)'),
        stackgroup = 'one',
         ) 
trace4 = dict(
        x = new_index,
        y = extra_fill['num_users'],
        hoverinfo = 'x+y',
        mode = 'lines',
        line=dict(width=0.5,
                  color='rgb(178, 241, 247)'),
        stackgroup = 'one',
         ) 

data = [trace0, trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4]
plotly.offline.iplot(data, filename='basic-area')
```

Renders
[image: stack-area-chart-plotly]

Comment: Thank you so much! This definitely worked. This answer was really helpful and explicative, and gave me the ultimate solution. :)